# Create full mobile app vs Create app that goes to a server which handles mobile

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have been playing around with PhoneGap for a little while, and getting it set up to work correctly with Google Drive API is proving to be far more difficult than setting up a website which does the same.

I am wondering if it would be more to my advantage to cease trying to make the full app work with phonegap, and instead use phonegap to access a hosted site.

Note that I do not wish to open the site in the default browser. The goal would be to make it appear to be an application (no borders, url, back button, etc), but have the web server handle everything behind the scenes.

I know PhoneGap has an In-App-Browser available. Is this something that is possible with it? Or does it only function for more limited use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use a `WebView` for your app, which display the webpage but give you the ability to control the layout around it. Running a WebView instead of native code may cost some performance but it's doable.